Using gtag dataLayer in Google Tag Manager
Although I started using Google Tag Manager log times ago, I have my legacy tracking (gtag) still available on my website.
So, in my GTM container, I can see all events(gtag and GTM dayaLayer) in the summary. That being said I have two different dataLayer on my website as follows:
1- gtag (dataLayer)
2- gtm (mainDataLayer)
Almost 100% of my e-commerce data is available in gtag dataLayer, and I can see all dataLayer push coming to the GTM from gtag with appropriate e-commerce data. Unfortunately, I can't use them because the name of dataLayer is different. I thought there might be another solution to use the gtag datacenter in Google Tag Manager. I need to set my eCommerce triggers based on gtag dataLayer push in GTM.
Is it feasible?



